# Kendo UI batch edit grid DropDownList does not show up

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I am using a kendo ui batch edit grid and I want to use a dropdown as a column of it.
I read other topics about this subject and I did these steps:

1- I created a list of text/value and named it as
 DocumetTypesSelectList in a viewbag like this:

```
            ViewBag.DocumetTypesSelectList = DocumentTypesBll.GetDocumentTypes().ToList().Select(item => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = item.DocumentTypeId.ToString(),
            Text = item.Title
        }).ToList();
```

2- I Cast the viewbag as a list of SelectItems in my view like this:

```
var DocumetTypesSelectList = ViewBag.DocumetTypesSelectList as List<SelectListItem> ?? new List<SelectListItem>();
```

3- I added a column to grid as follows:

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.DocumentTypeId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)DocumetTypesSelectList, dataFieldText: "Text", dataFieldValue: "Value")
```

but it does not open to select on of the items. on click you can change the value, and off click it shows the text using DocumetTypesSelectList .
Thanks In Advance
many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please explain little bit more about

> on click you can change the value, and off click it shows the text

It seems that here `(System.Collections.IEnumerable)DocumetTypesSelectList` you have missed your DocumetTypesSelectList object to pass on properly. You can do this in your controller by using ViewBag as `ViewBag.DocumetTypesSelectListEx = DocumetTypesSelectList` and use this ViewBag in your view as `(System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.DocumetTypesSelectListEx`

Second thing is, in your DocumetTypes you must have two fields one is for value and one is to display. It seems you have both as "Text" and "Value". Also check the demo [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did that too like this:  var DocumetTypesSelectList = ViewBag.DocumetTypesSelectList as List<SelectListItem> ?? new List<SelectListItem>();

Comment: explain little more especially 'but it does not open', edit your post and put some more code. I generally use it as columns.ForeignKey(c => c.AD_USER_ID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.UserList, "AD_USER_ID", "USERNAME")